# Continuous Looping Page on Blogger

Tags: javascript, loops, blogger, continuous

Is it possible to use Javascript to create a continuous scroll loop on Blogger, similar to these websites:
[Outpost Journal](http://www.outpostjournal.org/)
[Unfold](http://unfold.no/)

Once the scroll bar hits the bottom of the page, I would like it to loop back to the top.

Comment: a jquery version of the code has been shared http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993693/continuous-looping-page-not-infinite-scroll