# Loop Scrolling Website

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, infinite-loop

I want to create a website with the loop scrolling functionality of Unfold's [website](http://unfold.no/).

The website loops back to the top once you scroll all the way down to the bottom but it doesn't just jump to the top, it does it seamlessly where you don't even know your at the top again. It also allows the user to scroll up and it does the same thing.

I know this question has been asked and "answered" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993693/continuous-looping-page-not-infinite-scroll#new-answer) but it really wasn't exactly what I was looking for. The previous post's answers are decent but their solutions don't truly emulate unfolds seamless loop scrolling.

I'm looking for a solution that can scroll both ways and transitions smoothly between the end and top and vise versa.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try this `if (document.documentElement.clientHeight + $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height()) {
    $(document).scrollTop(0)
} else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 0) {
    $(document).scrollTop($(document).height())
}`

Comment: Yeah no that's not working for me.

Comment: thats the answer from the link you included.Anyway good to know i could help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continuous Looping Page (Not Infinite Scroll)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993693/continuous-looping-page-not-infinite-scroll)

Comment: it spits out an error saying: Unable to get property 'scrollHeight' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: @MikeRoss That answer didn't work.

Comment: post the code in question which you tried and giving you error because the code i provided you it doesnt have `scrollHeight` in it. It may be `id` of some tag in your `html`.

Comment: The error is coming from google's jquery.min.js.

Comment: add your html and javascript code in the question that will help more understanding the error

Answer (score 0):

Well try using this code

```
if (document.documentElement.clientHeight + $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height()) {
    $(document).scrollTop(0)
} else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 1) {
    $(document).scrollTop($(document).height())
}
```