# Infinite continuous looping scroll on mobile

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a small problem with my looping scroll. It works pretty well on larger displays, but on handheld devices it glitches quite a lot. I'm not sure where I'm doing something wrong or where I should adjust the code to work on mobile as well.

Link to site: https://studio-6-9ede0f.webflow.io/

Here's what I got so far:

```
var origDivHeight = document.querySelector(".infinite").offsetHeight;

var clone=$(".infinite").contents().clone();
clone.appendTo(".infinite");
clone.prependTo(".infinite");

$(document).scroll(function(){ 

    var scrollWindowPos = $(document).scrollTop(); 

    if(scrollWindowPos >= origDivHeight ) { 
        $(document).scrollTop(0); 
    }
    if(scrollWindowPos <= 0 ) { 
         $(document).scrollTop(origDivHeight); 
    }

});

window.scrollBy(0, 1);
window.scrollBy(0, -1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work based on this codepen: https://codepen.io/vincentorback/pen/zxRyzj

Sharing it here as well if somebody finds it useful:

```
<style>

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
  
.infinite {
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.clone {
  height: 50vw;
}
  
</style>

<script>

    var doc = window.document,
    context = doc.querySelector('.infinite'),
    clones = context.querySelectorAll('.clone'),
    disableScroll = false,
    scrollHeight = 0,
    scrollPos = 0,
    clonesHeight = 0,
    i = 0;

    function getScrollPos () {
      return (context.pageYOffset || context.scrollTop) - (context.clientTop || 0);
    }

    function setScrollPos (pos) {
      context.scrollTop = pos;
    }

    function getClonesHeight () {
      clonesHeight = 0;

      for (i = 0; i < clones.length; i += 1) {
        clonesHeight = clonesHeight + clones[i].offsetHeight;
      }

      return clonesHeight;
    }

    function reCalc () {
      scrollPos = getScrollPos();
      scrollHeight = context.scrollHeight;
      clonesHeight = getClonesHeight();

      if (scrollPos <= 0) {
        setScrollPos(1); // Scroll 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
      }
    }

    function scrollUpdate () {
      if (!disableScroll) {
        scrollPos = getScrollPos();

        if (clonesHeight + scrollPos >= scrollHeight) {
          // Scroll to the top when you’ve reached the bottom
          setScrollPos(1); // Scroll down 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
          disableScroll = true;
        } else if (scrollPos <= 0) {
          // Scroll to the bottom when you reach the top
          setScrollPos(scrollHeight - clonesHeight);
          disableScroll = true;
        }
      }

      if (disableScroll) {
        // Disable scroll-jumping for a short time to avoid flickering
        window.setTimeout(function () {
          disableScroll = false;
        }, 40);
      }
    }

    function init () {
      reCalc();

      context.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollUpdate);
      }, false);

      window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(reCalc);
      }, false);
    }

    if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
      init()
    } else {
      doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false)
    }

</script>
```